# C# - Multiplying Vector3 by float value returns rounded value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity2020
This string:

`Debug.Log(new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * 1.25f);` 
returns `(1.3, 0.0, 0.0)`.
Why?

Comment: I would guess this is just how the `ToString` override works. What happens if you do this: `Debug.Log((new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * 1.25f).ToString("F3"))` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just how the `ToString` override works. You can specify how the numbers are format by using different overrides. For example:

```
var vector = new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * 1.25f;
Debug.Log(vector.ToString("F3"));
```

Or individually log out the values:

```
var formatString = "F3";
Debug.Log($"Vector is X:{vector.X.ToString(formatString)}, Y:{vector.Y.ToString(formatString)}, Z:{vector.Z.ToString(formatString)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the Vector3 is converted to a string and 1 digit precision is Unity 2020's default.

If you want something else you need to explicitly call [Vector3.ToString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ToString.html) with a format specifier.

```
Debug.Log((new Vector3(1,0,0) * 1.25f).ToString("F2"));
```

Comment: Oh, ok I just wanted to check the value and problem was about ToString.
This string does better Debug.Log((new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * 1.25f)[0]);
Thanks all!